# Cannot use Red Hat Optional channel with yum: repomd.xml not found

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, yum, rpm

I need to install some packages that are in the optional repository channel of RHEL (like libtiff).

I followed this [instructions](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/392003), but when I try to yum update I get this error:

[image]

The issue is similar to this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1091450/centos-7-2-yum-repo-configuration-fails), so I have tried the following commands:

```
echo 7 > /etc/yum/vars/releasever
rm -fr /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7
yum clean all
```

But I still get the same error. Is the repository valid? If yes what did I miss?